# Is it possible to open multiple URLs from a .txt and scrape all the webpages at once?

Tags: python, file, url

I can't understand how to deal with more than one URL. This is what I've tried so far, but it's only scraping the last URL from the list:

```
from twill.commands import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

with open('urls.txt') as inf:
    urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    for url in urls:
        line = url 

site = urlopen(url)   

soup = BeautifulSoup(site)

for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'subjectCell'}):
    print td.find('a').text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop over all of the URLs, you have to put the code that processes each URL into the loop. But you haven't done that. All you have is:

```
for url in urls:
    line = url
```

This will reassign the variables `url` and `line` over and over, finally leaving them both pointing to the last URL. And then, when you call `size = urlopen(url)` outside the loop, it will work on the last URL.

Try this:

```
with open('urls.txt') as inf:
    urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    for url in urls:
        site = urlopen(url)   
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site)
        for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'subjectCell'}):
            print td.find('a').text
```

Comment: i'm getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: Sorry, you either need to put all the work on `urls` into the `with` statement, or make `urls` into a list instead of a generator. I've fixed the indent. But, more importantly: do you understand the difference between this code, and your code with everything outside the loop?

Comment: yes,at first i tried to put everything inside the loop, but i was getting errors,then i separated and it worked but only with the last...

Comment: oh, it worked now. i think the problem was an empty line in the file! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

These code should be inside the for loop

```
site = urlopen(url)   

soup = BeautifulSoup(site)

for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'subjectCell'}):
    print td.find('a').text
```

Then they will be call for each of the url.

Comment: I guess you mean the for loop in the WITH-context? ;-) The way you stated it is too ambiguous. Welcome to SO btw!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put everything you want to do with each url into the `for` loop:

```
with open('urls.txt') as inf:
    urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    for url in urls:
        site = urlopen(url)   
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site)

        for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'subjectCell'}):
            print td.find('a').text
```